# "Reduce" function for Series

Tags: python, performance, pandas, vectorization, reduce

Is there an analog for `reduce` for a pandas Series?

For example, the analog for `map` is [pd.Series.apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply), but I can't find any analog for `reduce`.

---

My application is, I have a pandas Series of lists:

```
>>> business["categories"].head()

0                      ['Doctors', 'Health & Medical']
1                                        ['Nightlife']
2                 ['Active Life', 'Mini Golf', 'Golf']
3    ['Shopping', 'Home Services', 'Internet Servic...
4    ['Bars', 'American (New)', 'Nightlife', 'Loung...
Name: categories, dtype: object
```

I'd like to merge the Series of lists together using `reduce`, like so:

```
categories = reduce(lambda l1, l2: l1 + l2, categories)
```

but this takes a horrific time because merging two lists together is `O(n)` time in Python. I'm hoping that `pd.Series` has a vectorized way to perform this faster.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### With `itertools.chain()` on the values

This could be faster:

```
from itertools import chain
categories = list(chain.from_iterable(categories.values))
```

### Performance

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import chain

categories = pd.Series([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e']] * 1000)

%timeit list(chain.from_iterable(categories.values))
1000 loops, best of 3: 231 µs per loop

%timeit list(chain(*categories.values.flat))
1000 loops, best of 3: 237 µs per loop

%timeit reduce(lambda l1, l2: l1 + l2, categories)
100 loops, best of 3: 15.8 ms per loop
```

For this data set the `chain`ing is about 68x faster.

### Vectorization?

Vectorization works when you have native NumPy data types (pandas uses NumPy for its data after all). Since we have lists in the Series already and want a list as result, it is rather unlikely that vectorization will speed things up. The conversion between standard Python objects and pandas/NumPy data types will likely eat up all the performance you might get from the vectorization. I made one attempt to vectorize the algorithm in another answer.

Comment: Interesting. I'll be interested in how those optimizations for chain are implemented under the hood.

Comment: The reduce builds a lot of intermediate lists that all require memory allocation. Allocating memory is slow. Using `chain` significantly  reduces the number of memory allocations.

Comment: It works. But I was hoping for a more vectorized approach. For now, I'll abstain from choosing this as the answer, even though it's very good.

Comment: I added a vectorized solution in another answer. But it is much slower. See explanation above why.

Comment: I just ran the performance metrics and on my machine the second algorithm consistently was ~30 µs faster. Maybe you can run them again and update the answer? Could be that some Python performance has changed.

Answer (score 7):

### Vectorized but slow

You can use NumPy's  `concatenate`:

```
import numpy as np

list(np.concatenate(categories.values))
```

### Performance

But we have lists, i.e. Python objects already. So the vectorization has to switch back and forth between Python objects and NumPy data types. This make things slow:

```
categories = pd.Series([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e']] * 1000)

%timeit list(np.concatenate(categories.values))
100 loops, best of 3: 7.66 ms per loop

%timeit np.concatenate(categories.values)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.33 ms per loop

%timeit list(chain.from_iterable(categories.values))
1000 loops, best of 3: 231 µs per loop
```

Comment: If the input were given in numpy, this would have been the faster one, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can try your luck with `business["categories"].str.join('')`, but I am guessing that Pandas uses Pythons string functions. I doubt you can do better tha what Python already offers you.

Answer (score 0):

I used `"".join(business["categories"])`

It is much faster than `business["categories"].str.join('')` but still 4 times slower than the `itertools.chain` method. I preferred it because it is more readable and no import is required.

Answer (score 0):

if you have None values, you can filter them first

```py
from itertools import chain

my_series = my_df.apply(lambda x: [j for j in x if j != None])
list(chain.from_iterable(my_series.values))
```